# C++ Socket Connect Issue

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I have a socket connect function, the issue is that if the client is started before the server, the connection shows as connected, but for some reason returns fails.  I am not sure where the failure is and would really appreciate any help:

The function is:

```
bool IPV4Socket::Connect( std::string hostname
                    , unsigned short remotePort
                    , TimeoutValue *timeout )
{
    AddrInfo getResults;
    AddrInfo getaddrinfoHints;
    int connReturn = 0;
    SockAddr_In *addrData;
    bool connectSuccess = false;
    std::string service = std::to_string( remotePort );

    getaddrinfoHints.ai_family = AddressFamily_inet;
    getaddrinfoHints.ai_socktype = SockType_stream;

    if ( m_socketAdaptor->getaddrinfo( hostname
                                 , service
                                 , &getaddrinfoHints
                                 , &getResults ) != 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    addrData = (SockAddr_In *)&( *getResults.ai_addr.begin() );

    connReturn = m_socketAdaptor->connect( m_socket
                                         , (const Sockaddr *)addrData
                                         , (int)getResults.ai_addrlen );

    if ( connReturn == SocketError)
    {
        int m_lastErrorCode = m_socketAdaptor->GetLastError();

        //  Connection error : FATAL 
        if ( ( m_lastErrorCode != SockErr_EWOULDBLOCK) &&
             ( m_lastErrorCode != SockErr_EALREADY ) )
        {
            connectSuccess = false;
        }
        else
        {
           SocketSet writeFDS;
           SocketSet exceptFDS;
           int selectReturn = 0;

           //  Clear all the socket FDS structures
           SocketSet_ZERO( &writeFDS );
           SocketSet_ZERO( &exceptFDS );

           //  Put the socket into the FDS structures
           SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &writeFDS );
           SocketSet_SET( m_socket, &exceptFDS );

           selectReturn = m_socketAdaptor->select( -1
                                                 , NULL
                                              , &writeFDS
                                              , &exceptFDS
                                              , timeout );

           if ( selectReturn == SocketError )
           {
               //  Any errors are bad
               connectSuccess = false;
           }
           else if ( selectReturn > 0 )
           {
                //  Check for error (exception) first
                if ( m_socketAdaptor->SocketSet_ISSET( m_socket, &exceptFDS ) )
                {
                    connectSuccess = false;
                }
                else if ( m_socketAdaptor->SocketSet_ISSET( m_socket, &writeFDS ) )
                {
                    //   Select returned 'writable', we're connected!
                    connectSuccess = true;
                    m_isConnected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        connectSuccess = true;
        m_isConnected = true;
    }

    return connectSuccess;
}
```

I am not sure if I am missing the point, or if I have overly complicated the function.

Helllp :)

Notes:
   * By the way, m_socketAdaptor-> functions are just wrappers.
   * If you start server and then client, it works...

Comment: what does netstat show when the client is running before starting the server?

Comment: @UmamaheshP using 'netstat -a -p tcp 10' I get : TCP    127.0.0.1:51074        WINDEVSRV:3490   SYN_SENT

Comment: That is expected behavior. Sending syn is the first step of TCP hand shake. If the server is not listening on the port, then the connection will fail. The client needs to try connecting again.

Comment: @UmamaheshP On the server side I get a notifications that client connected, connect returns failed (false) with already connected (10056).  This lead me to think connect   is wrong?

Comment: If no program is listening on the listener port, then no client will be able to make a connection. If the client fails to connect then that is an expected behavior. does netstat show the client connected to the server? You need to run netstat on server and client side unless you are running both the client and the server on the same machine.

Comment: @UmamaheshP TCP    127.0.0.1:3490         WINDEVSRV:51074  ESTABLISHED - but Connect() returned not connected (false) .. confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103910/discussion-between-umamahesh-p-and-paul-morriss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reconnect a socket which has already failed to connect. You have to close it and create a new socket. Therefore that should be done in the connect method, not wherever it is done now.